# How to find and calculate the number of duplicated rows between two different dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

How could I know duplicated numbers of rows between different data frames? and make new columns?

data frame 1:

```
c_x   c_y

dan    kim

lee    kim

bob    dan

bob    uni
```

data frame 2:

```
c_x   c_y    movie

kim    kim    a

lee    kim    a

kim    lee    b

dan    bob    c

bob    dan    f

bob    uni    a

uni    bob    f
```

I want to calculate duplicated number of rows based on two data frame. In specific, I want to calculate the number of duplicated rows regardless of column order. Also, I want to make new columns of movies

I want a final data frame like this.

```
df1
c_x   c_y    movie1    movie2   number

dan    kim    nan       nan       0

lee    kim     a         b        2

bob    dan     c         f        2

bob    uni     a         f        2
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sorted both DataFrames - columns `c_x` and `c_y`, for `movies` is used [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), count non missing values by [`DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) and append to `df1`:

```
df2[['c_x','c_y']] = np.sort(df2[['c_x','c_y']], axis=1)

df2['g'] = df2.groupby(['c_x','c_y']).cumcount().add(1)

df2 = df2.pivot(index=['c_x','c_y'], columns='g', values='movie').add_prefix('movie')
df2['number'] = df2.count(axis=1)
print (df2)
g       movie1 movie2  number
c_x c_y                      
bob dan      c      f       2
    uni      a      f       2
kim kim      a    NaN       1
    lee      a      b       2
```

And then:

```
df1[['c_x','c_y']] = np.sort(df1[['c_x','c_y']], axis=1)

df = df1.join(df2, on=['c_x','c_y'])
```